# The display range of TIMESTAMP type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-timestamp

In MySQL Docs, the range of `TIMESTAMP` is from `'1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07.499999'` UTC.

But this SQL statement can be execute and display correctly:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 0.00001) FROM DUAL;
```

The result is `'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000010'`. Out of the range?

I know that timestamp is the differ that is between current time and '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000'.
Is the unit of differ second or millsecond? And is the implement of `TIMESTAMP` based the `BIGINT` (or `long`)?

MySQL Docs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enskN.png)

And the result of SQL statement:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADHkR.png)

Comment: Timestamp function returns a DATETIME https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/xremQ0gS

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And the mean is that mysql only check data in the process that it insert the data into table?